# Erro ao gerar relatório

Tags: javafx, ireport, relatório

Tenho uma aplicação `JavaFX` onde tenho um botão que gera relatórios. Porém quando tento gerar o relatório acontece esse erro:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Esse é meu método que gera o relatório:

```
 @FXML
     private void gerarRelatorio(){
         try {
            Map<String, Object> filtro = new HashMap<>();
            InputStream image = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/justi/view/relatorios/leaf_banner_green.png");
           filtro.put("status", cbStatus.getValue().toString());
            filtro.put("IMAGE", image);


            InputStream inputStreamReal = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/justi/view/relatorios/contratos.jasper");
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStreamReal, filtro, ConexaoMysql.abrir());

            JasperViewer jrviewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
            jrviewer.setVisible(true);
            jrviewer.toFront();

        } catch (JRException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FrmListarCadastrosController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

     }
```

Comment: Qual é a versão do seu JDK?

Comment: 1.8, pode ser falta de bibliotecas?

Comment: Não sei, mas eu já tive um problema parecido e eu "acho" que resolvi atualizando do 1.7u25 para o 1.7u45. Eu ainda tenho essa pergunta aberta e não configurei um ambiente de testes para chegar a uma conclusão. Mas no seu caso, o problema pode ser outro, e eu a princípio não sei dizer qual.

Comment: Beleza, vou dar uma fuçada aqui e ver o que consigo. O duro é que não mostra a linha do erro rsrs.

Comment: Sim, eu já passei por isso e é terrível. Me parece algum bug na linguagem, sei lá.

Comment: Vamos ver, obrigado por tentar ajudar